# pressing keys together in pyautogui to make them make a function?

Tags: python, pyautogui

I have been recently trying to create a program that makes new folder in python(pyautogui).
Here is my code:

```
import pyautogui;# import the library
pyautogui.press('ctrl');# makes our program to press 'ctrl'
pyautogui.press('n');# makes our program to press 'n'
```

Apparently what it does instead is pressing `ctrl` and `n`  individually and I want from them to be pressed together. Please help.

Comment: See [second snippet in the docs](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#the-press-keydown-and-keyup-functions) as a hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#the-press-keydown-and-keyup-functions):

> The `press()` function is really just a wrapper for the `keyDown()`
> and `keyUp()` functions, which simulate pressing a key down and then
> releasing it up.

As you want to combine several key presses, you need to call `keyDown()` and `keyUp()` separately:

```
pyautogui.keyDown('ctrl')
pyautogui.press('n')
pyautogui.keyUp('ctrl')
```